# How to define a simple pipe function with generics?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote a simple pipe function that accepts either asynchronous functions, or just values that are passed on without being executed.

I really tried to define it using generics but didn't make it so reverted to using `unknown` instead.
What I have:

```
export const pipe = (...args: Array<unknown>): Promise<unknown> | unknown =>
  args.reduce((prev, exec) => {
    if (typeof exec !== 'function') {
      return exec;
    }

    const getNextInPipe = async (): Promise<unknown> => {
      return exec(await prev);
    };

    const value = getNextInPipe();
    return value;
  });
```

I tried to write it like this:

```
export const pipe = <T,>(...args: Array<unknown>): unknown =>
  args.reduce((prev, exec) => {
    if (typeof exec !== 'function') {
      return exec;
    }

    const getNextInPipe = async (): Promise<T> => {
      return exec(await prev);
    };

    const value = getNextInPipe();
    return value;
  });
```

But I don't know how to replace the other `unknown`, and if it can be done? Because the type of output of each function in the pipe doesn't depend on the type of input.

I'm still new to generics, thanks in advance

Comment: What types of calls are you trying to support? Do you want to allow `pipe()` with no arguments (which is a runtime error)?  Do you want to allow `pipe(3,4,5)` (which ends up completely ignoring the `3` and the `4` and returning `5`?)  It seems the only useful sort of call is `pipe(initValue, func0, func1, func2, ...)` where each function accepts as input the (awaited) output of the previous input.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1AXyw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz wow that's amazing thank you so much for taking the time to write this, and you're totally right the only useful call is an initial value and then functions. I honestly barely understand the syntax you wrote, I'll try to dive deeper into learning this, thanks a lot again!

Comment: @jcalz, if it's ok to ask, how would you recommend me to learn that advance usage of generics? I do have a nice ts Udemy course but it's pretty basic. Maybe a book, or a video course?

Comment: My comment does not constitute an answer; I'll write up a full answer when I get a chance explaining.  I'm not sure what to recommend to others to learn advanced TS; I spent and spend a lot of time reading the release notes and github issues, but I don't think that's going to get anyone up to speed quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function might be simple (that's debatable anyway) but the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) typings are anything but.  You are trying to represent a "chain" of types of arbitrary length.  Essentially you start with an initial value of type `I`, and then maybe a function of a type like `(input: Awaited<I>) => Promise<Awaited<TFirst>>` for some output type `TFirst`, and then maybe a  function of a type like `(input: Awaited<TFirst>) => Promise<Awaited<TSecond>>`, etc. etc., and finally ending on a function of a type like `(input: Awaited<TPenultimate>) => Promise<Awaited<TLast>>`, and then the output of `pipe()` is a value of type `Promise<Awaited<TLast>>`, unless there were no functions and just an input `I`, in which case the output is `I`.

The parts with [the `Awaited` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) are dealing with the fact that if you `await` a non-promise value you get the value, so `Awaited<string>` is `string`, and `Awaited<Promise<string>>` is `string`... and you can't really nest promises, so `Awaited<Promise<Promise<string>>>` is also `string`.

So one approach to `pipe()` would look like this:

```
const pipe: <I, T extends any[]>(
  init: I,
  ...fns: { [N in keyof T]: (input: Awaited<Idx<[I, ...T], N>>) => T[N] }
) => T extends [...infer _, infer R] ? Promise<Awaited<R>> : I =
  (...args: any[]): any => args.reduce((prev, exec) => {
    if (typeof exec !== 'function') {
      return exec;
    }

    const getNextInPipe = async () => {
      return exec(await prev);
    };

    const value = getNextInPipe();
    return value;
  });

type Idx<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

The `I` type parameter corresponds to the type of the `init` function parameter.  The `T` type parameter corresponds to the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the output types of each of the functions in the `fns` rest parameter.  So if there are two functions and the first function returns a `Promise<boolean>` and the second function returns a `string`, then `T` will be `[Promise<boolean>, string]`.

The type of the `fns` argument is where the complexity lives.  For the element of `fns` at numericlike index `N` (think `0` for the first one, `1` for the second one), we know that the output type is the `N`th element of `T`, or the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[N]`.  That's straightforward enough.  But the input type comes from the *previous* element of `T`.  Or maybe `I`.  We represent that by first making `[I, ...T]`, which uses a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to represent prepending `I` to `T`.  Then we just need the `N`th element of that.  Conceptually that's the indexed access `[I, ...T][N]`.  But the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that every numeric index `N` of the `T` tuple type will also be an index on the `[I, ...T]` tuple type.  So I need to use the `Idx` helper type to convince the compiler to perform that indexing.

As for the output type, we need to tease apart `T` to find its last element `R` (using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)).  If that exists, then we are returning a value of type `Promise<Awaited<R>>`.  If not, it's because `T` is empty so we're just returning `I`.

Whew.

---

Okay let's test it.  First of all the supported uses:

```
const z = pipe(3, (n: number) => n.toFixed(2), (s: string) => s.length === 4)
// const pipe: <3, [string, boolean]>(
//   init: 3, 
//   fns_0: (input: 3) => string, 
//   fns_1: (input: string) => boolean
// ) => Promise<boolean>
// const z: Promise<boolean>
z.then(v => console.log("z is", v)) // z is true

const y = pipe(4);
// const pipe: <4, []>(init: 4) => 4
// const y: 4
console.log("y is", y) // y is 4

const x = pipe(50, (n: number) => new Promise<string>(
  r => setTimeout(() => { r(n.toFixed(3)) }, 1000)), 
  (s: string) => s.length === 4);
// const pipe: <50, [Promise<string>, boolean]>(
//   init: 50, 
//   fns_0: (input: 50) => Promise<string>, 
//   fns_1: (input: string) => boolean
// ) => Promise<boolean>
// const x: Promise<boolean>
x.then(v => console.log("x is", v)) // x is false
```

That all looks good.  `z` and `x` are promises of the expected type, while `y` is just a numeric value. Now for the unsupported cases:

```
pipe(); // error!  
// Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.

pipe(10, 20, 30); // error! 
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(input: 10) => unknown'.

pipe(10, (x: string) => x.toUpperCase()) // error!     
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

pipe(10, (x: number) => x.toFixed(2), (x: boolean) => x ? "y" : "n") // error!
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

Those all fail for violating constraints on the function.  It needs at least one argument, and only the first argument can be a non-function.  Each function needs to accept the awaited response of the previous function (or the initial value), and if it does not, then you get an error.

---

So that's about as good a job as I can do.  It's not *perfect*; I'm sure you could find edge cases if you look.  The obvious one is if you don't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the callback parameters then inference might fail.  Something like `pipe(10, x => x.toFixed(), y => y.toFixed())` should yield an error but doesn't, because the compiler fails to infer that `x` should be a `number` and it falls back to `any`, after which all the inputs and outputs are `any`.  If you want it to be caught you need to write `pipe(10, (x: number)=>x.toFixed(), (y: number)=>y.toFixed())`.  There may be tweaks that can improve this, but I'm not going to spend any more time trying to find them here.

The main point is that you can represent this sort of thing but it's not simple.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgDwDwBUA0UDSA+KBeLKCBYCAOzgGcoBrCEAewDMoUoB+VgbUwF0oAXFDIQAbhABOAbgCwAKADGDMpWBQwAS0hCkMDG2KkK1AIZkQXXtgAU8qFA1kNwIXrtQAdF6YqhAbyguADkHMlp6ZlZeIWtHMABXFygAQQB3E2cIOF1EJC49Ty8UXgwg7GwASnxcFGD+AF95KrwaohJyKkCvD0cmSSgAfQxe-oAlfk4ABQkGAFsNSggkNIzSbNHywVh8d2tukwkAc0ohMwteCtPzaqgD448JLPiFCGtrMEfRDGIIBWbcPzuewaFjWUCQSI-BRQACEeAIAHImPEyApgBplAiqoC5PY8VBHsB4hIwlDZLi8Y05ECoEoVGpDhBgEFDDAyJMtNACCZKCBUVBrP8oDj8fZCcTSQhftYTOlnOpPhVyfj6uSaXTVFBRCYADbxLlQRnM1nszmC5V48UkrW6-UW+pK+TyDVqABe+HUZoAzBhrGQhGR4rMAEaSIVkDzABgAMQ0Urg1gATBVfScoKoJI5DkLKB4deRDsAABb4eFQAAsFXkAHpq7TlJrNNooEgfYEM1mMMGGAx82YrLY5LW8Y5nEI2zW6-YfJQBgAGGJxRLjnPATNkQ4YSd4mcDACMi7ICSSHY3Qu7vYgZm3QumcwWSwvfbI2G3LqgrqEd-miyQT6vL7yK6kZFuQ1iiDcGqXnmDCHNYABE7oLPBGCiBUVTDkh1BrvqTqKA2aggB6TavJW5LDu+JE6OWGCWDYo5JJWNzlm+BFQCAQgsfhKjQTqsEIURyEYCAGF1oJ1Bcc6bEIMRZoAKxzr6-rCEGoYSOGECpFA34Pkgp6HDY7gSDcizACgGizBADCJG8QoBBIfqRjGcZZNYXroVA9QYHuc6+ehaC7Gm+k5nmBbFqWBBkax9Kes2SAKbROm-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)

Comment: Just want to say thank you so much for this detailed explanation I will investigate it and learn your answer